# fuzzylite visual c++ strange behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++

my problem is very strange.
In `visual c++` I want to use `fuzzylite library` to create a dll.
when I create my class that using library in the form (`myclass.h` , `myclass.cpp`)the project compiles fine.
and fuzzylite headers are included in the `myclass.h`

but if i add (`#include “stdafx.h”`) at the top of `myclass.cpp` or add (`#include “fl/Headers.h”`) to the `stdafx.h` I get about `100 errors`.
any idea?

**Update 1:**

```
//FuzzyCalc.h
#pragma once
#define __DLL_EXPORTS
#ifdef __DLL_EXPORTS
#define __DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define __DLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
class __DLL_API FuzzyCalc
     {
          public:
             FuzzyCalc();
            ~FuzzyCalc();
            double  getOutputValue(double val1, double val2);
    };


//FuzzyCalc.cpp
#include "fl/Headers.h"
#include "FuzzyCalc.h"
FuzzyCalc::FuzzyCalc()
    {
     }
FuzzyCalc::~FuzzyCalc()
    {
    }
double FuzzyCalc::getOutputValue(double val1, double val2)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
```

until this point every thing is normal and program compile and build succesful but if i add this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "fl/Headers.h"
#include "FuzzyCalc.h"
FuzzyCalc::FuzzyCalc()
  {
  }
FuzzyCalc::~FuzzyCalc()
  {
  }
double FuzzyCalc::getOutputValue(double val1, double val2)
  {
    return 0.0;
  }
```

I get some errors like thease:

```
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'a' fuzzyind      fuzzylite\fl\Operation.h  41  
Error   C2365   'T': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter' fuzzyind \fuzzylite\fl\Operation.h  41  
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'a'    fuzzyind    \fuzzylite\fl\Operation.h   41  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   fuzzyind    \fuzzylite\fl\Operation.h   41  
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body  fuzzyind \fuzzylite\fl\Operation.h  41  
Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition  fuzzyind    \fuzzylite\fl\term\Term.h   37  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before 'namespace'    fuzzyind    \fuzzylite\fl\term\Term.h   37  
Error   C1004   unexpected end-of-file found    fuzzyind fuzzyind\dllmain.cpp   19
```

just adding one line and every thing goes wrong.

Comment: Build a sample that is main and the headers you need. Then add the functionality you want line by line until it stops compiling. If that doesn't make the problem obvious, edit your question to add your code.This is what we call an MCVE, but you already knew that since you read the site help and the section on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem .
the problem is because addition of windows.h in the file stdafx.h.
in that file there are macro definitions such as min and max that conflict with fuzzylite library.
by adding a #define NOMINMAX before that include problem solved the true way is:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from     
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#include "fl/Headers.h"
```

hope this helps others.